# changing a pages header dynamically

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently  using this code to include specific content within a specified page

```
function add_profile( $content ) {
if( is_page('profile')) include_once('page-profile.php');
else { }
}

add_filter('the_content','add_profile');
```

Is there a way to alter the h1 for this page as well, allowing me to inject the current users display_name rather than the default wordpress page name?

Comment: You will need to edit your corresponding theme file ( which we do not know ) . `h1` is theme specific . alternatively use the same technique you had written here in your code .

Answer (score 1):

You can alter your theme or you can do it with jQuery.

Your html

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

Your jQuery

```
var h1 = jQuery('h1').text();
jQuery('h1').text( h1 +' Greg');
```

You can get the name from a html tag.

Edit: You can also filter the_title.

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'my_new_title');
function my_new_title($title) {
    $title = 'New Title ';
    return $title;
}
```

Comment: There is no wp hook I can use in PHP?

Comment: your filter worked! Thank you a million times!  One more followup question - anyway to set the post title as the current user username?  I tried using global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
 in my plugin file but it returns an error.  Ideas??

- edit - also that code changed the title of every page on my site so my custom name.  I use the if is_page but it still changed them all.